# OAuth 2.0 way of grant permissions in JS and use serverside, (no session)

Tags: javascript, facebook, session, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

I have created several apps by using FB.login() in the middle of the steps on a page, and rely on C# gaining access to the same session and thereby access (and save) the user info correctly.

```
JS:
FB.login(function (response) { if (response.session) {// user has authed} });

C#:
public FacebookSession CurrentSession { get { return (new CanvasAuthorizer()).Session; } }
```

In two days Facebook will remove the session support, which breaks this functionality. As I understand I am now required to have a page-reload before serverside can detect the granted permissions. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). It seems I have to either redirect the user to the login-box and then setup a callback, or still use javascript but reload the page once the user grants permissions.

This is really sad, since the apps works very well by showing the user the app-interface, before asking any permissions and reloading the page. Does anyone know how to get the JS coupled to the serverside once again?

Comment: Hm it seems to work if I use the true url, http://mydomain/default but not when used inside a page tab ..

Comment: I have fixed it temporarily now by adding a <input type="hidden">, setting it to the accesstoken I get back from FB.login and then read this in serverside. Works, but really not a good solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you are on v5.2.1 which supports the new cookie format and in js set oauth:true when calling login.

Your existing code will continue to work without any server side (c#) changes.